# resizing image in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Iam trying to change the image size with the click of a button. like (if i click on button named 100 the image size should turn to 100x100).

The html code is:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img class="image" src="pic.jpg" alt="pic">
    <div class="btn">
    <button type="button" class="h100xw100">100</button>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="h200xw200">200</button>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="h300xw300">300</button>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="h400xw400">400</button>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

The JS code is

```
   

      var image= document.getElementsByTagName("img");

      for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("button").length;i++)
        {
         document.getElementsByTagName("button")[i].addEventListener("click",function()
        { 
         action(this.innerHTML);});
           }
              function action(value)
                  {
           for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("button").length;i++)
               {
                  switch(value)
                {
                    case "100": 
                            image.style.width="100";
                            image.style.height="100";
                                     break;

                    case "200" :
                            image.style.width="200";
                            image.style.height="200";
                                     break;
        
                    case "300" :
                            image.style.width="300";
                            image.style.height="300";
                                     break;

                    case "400" :
                             image.style.width="400";
                             image.style.height="400";
                                     break;

        default: alert("max-size reached");

                   }
                      }
                          }
```

I have even used querySelector too. but not working!!

I have also tried calling function action without the annonymous function

like

document.getElementsByTagName("button")[i].addEventListener("click",action);

Comment: Is your method of getting your object is working when you execute your code?

Comment: yes it's working.

Comment: Can you skip the `switch` and directly assign `value` to `width` and `height`?

Answer (score 0):

I did two smaller fixes. Below is code snippet, which will work:

```
<script>
        var image = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]; //<--------This is Array

        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("button").length; i++) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                action(this.innerHTML);
            });
        }
        function action(value) {
            for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("button").length; i++) {
                switch (value) {
                    case "100":
                        image.style.width = "100px"; //<--- Add "px"
                        image.style.height = "100px";
                        break;

                    case "200":
                        image.style.width = "200px";
                        image.style.height = "200px";
                        break;

                    case "300":
                        image.style.width = "300px";
                        image.style.height = "300px";
                        break;

                    case "400":
                        image.style.width = "400px";
                        image.style.height = "400px";
                        break;

                    default: alert("max-size reached");

                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: please help me by telling how treating 'img' as array worked.

Comment: Note: getElementsByTagName() method returns a collection of all element in document as specified with name of element(here in this case is "img") which you have passed. If you console that line you will see an Array

Answer (score 0):

```js
var images=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var buttons=document.getElementsByTagName("button");

function btnClick(btn) {
  for(var img=0; img<images.length; img++) {
    images[img].style.width=buttons[btn].textContent+"px";
    images[img].style.height=buttons[btn].textContent+"px";
  }
}

for(var btn=0; btn<buttons.length; btn++) {
  buttons[btn].setAttribute("onclick", "btnClick("+btn+")");
}
```

```html
<button>10</button>
<button>20</button>
<button>30</button>
<button>40</button>
<hr>
<img width="35" height="25">
<img width="28" height="50">
<img width="57" height="75">
```

Comment: You are welcome.
Sorry I didn't use event listeners - I tried, but I guess I'm not good enough with them yet.
I will appreciate Selecting my answer - this is how people advance here.